# How do I find the amount of items being selected in a ListBox?

Tags: c#, listbox

I'm trying to find out just how many items are being selected when the user clicks the button.

Here is what I've tried:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListItem li;
    int x = 0;
    foreach ( li in listBox1.Items) 
    {
        if (li.Selected == true)
        {
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

But instead it's giving me an error.

```
Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement
```

Also, is there a specific method in Windows Form Application that would count the amount of items in a List Box?

Comment: Start with "You're doing it wrong.". I pointed you to the documentation on `ListBox` in a comment to your previous question, and even suggested looking at properties starting with `Selected` as a clue. How could you miss [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx), which gives you a collection containing **only the selected items**? The collection has a property that indicates how many entries it contains. No loop, no counter. **Read the documentation**. :-)

Comment: With regard to you "Also": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method in ListBox class to get the amount of selected item:

```
int numberSelectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the list of selected items. Check the count property istBox1.SelectedItems.Count to get the list of items selected.

```
var selectedItems = listBox1.SelectedItems;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindices%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`SelectedItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the count of selected items like below

`listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count`

Or

`listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count`

and `Items.Count` to get amount of items in a List Box

```
ListBox1.Items.Count
```

in your`Foreach` you need to specify the `Type`, Try below

```
int x = 0;
foreach(ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected) 
       x++;
}
```